# Sequelize find all birthdays between two dates

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm currently trying to find all customers that have their birthday between dateX and dateY using Sequelize.
I am using Op.between, but the issue I am running into is that it will obviously only return birthdays in that year.
For example, let's assume dateX = 01.01.2020 and dateY 31.01.2020, then it will return all customers born in January 2020, but not people born in January of earlier years.

Any tips on how to get this done?

This is my current code:

```
db.customer.findAll({
            where: {
                active: true,
                dateOfBirth: {
                    [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
                }
            },
            order: [['dateOfBirth', 'ASC']]
        });
```

Comment: Can you please add what is the sql query generated by this. There is no direct way to do what you need via sequelize but we can find out a way to do. Also add what input you want to give and some output examples that covers range of what can be outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in a string format, you could just do

`[Op.startsWith]: '01'`

Comment: Nice thought, but this will only work if start and end dates are within the same month.